# Is it possible to use arrow functions in react props?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render components by mapping over a list that holds these components in JavaScript object literals.
it iterates over the list and renders the components as desired, however,  inside the `Child` component, I can see the `props.myFunc` is undefined, which was weird at first because changing myFunc to a regular JavaScript function (not arrow style) makes it work just fine, so what's happening?

- Using react 18
- This is not  a bug in React 18, because I tried to run the same code on React 17, and it did same behavior.

```js
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.myFunc);
    return <></>;
  }
}
class Parent extends Component {
  list = [
    { btn: <Child myFunc={this.arrowFunc} /> },
    { btn: <Child myFunc={this.arrowFunc} /> },
    { btn: <Child myFunc={this.arrowFunc} /> },
  ];
  arrowFunc = () => {};
  render() {
    return this.list.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.btn}</div>);
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

Comment: `list` is initialised before `arrowFunc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is field initialization by another field in TypeScript permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948622/is-field-initialization-by-another-field-in-typescript-permitted)

Comment: so it is a JavaScript behavior, ok thanks. I thought it was something because of Babel, since we can use public fields in React classes,

Comment: You have misspelled `myFunc`.

Comment: @user3840170, I don't know TypeScript

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can ignore the `private` keyword and type annotations.

Comment: @JLRishe ️️️, my apologies, I misspelled it, corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the arrow function syntax is an [Experimental Feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal). As you suspected you need to [Enable it in babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Then main advantage of this syntax is that you don't need to bind your handler. You'll find more details in the [React documentation about handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

---

**EDIT:**

Going beyond the scope of your question, storing the `Child` component in the list makes it a bit hard to understand what's going on. Generally speaking, you code could be refactored like so :

```js
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.myFunc);
    return <></>;
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  list = [
    { btn: {...someProps}},
    { btn: {...someProps} },
    { btn: {...someProps} },
  ];
  arrowFunc = () => {};
  render() {
    return this.list.map((item) => <Child {...item.btn} key={i} />);
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

This also remove the need for the extra `div`. However it might not do exactly what you want, it's hard to tell without a specific use case